# Subset dataframe on a column with type = category

Tags: python, pandas

I'm puzzled as to why the below code doesn't work. I created the column `AgeBands` with the `pd.cut` function, so the type is category. In theory, I should be able to subset on it like I would on a string column, but when I try that the resulting dataframe `new_df` has zero rows. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [22, 38, 26, 35, 35, 65]})
df['AgeBands'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], [0,10,20,30,40,50,max(df['Age'])])

new_df = df[df['AgeBands'] == '(30-40]']
new_df.shape
```

When running `df.info()` I have confirmation the `AgeBands` is indeed of type category:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Age         6 non-null int64
AgeBands    6 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 174.0 bytes
```

Comment: Is '(30-40]' a regex ?

Comment: @Tbaki - no, (30-40] is the value AgeBands has from pd.cut. It is a string, but maybe Python sees it as a regex? I'll look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspell what you had in the df, it's `'(30, 40]'`, not `'(30-40]'`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : [22, 38, 26, 35, 35, 65]})
df['AgeBands'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], [0,10,20,30,40,50,max(df['Age'])])

new_df = df[df['AgeBands'] == '(30, 40]']
new_df
```

ouput

```
    Age AgeBands
1   38  (30, 40]
3   35  (30, 40]
4   35  (30, 40]
```

Comment: @Tbaki - this was it. This embarrassing, thank you for your quick find.

Comment: @BogdanC No problem, happen to the best of us, have a good day. :D

Comment: @BogdanC That's not embarassing. I thought that was the problem the moment i saw your code. But while checking I forgot to add a print(dataframe) so all I saw was the previous output in the interpreter (one with empty dataframe) and thought wow this is more complex. Was reading through the docs,articles. It hurts more than embarrassment.

Comment: @s_vishnu same, but i had the ideas to use df['AgeBands'].iloc[1]  instead of '(30-40]' which was working, so i figured out like this. : )

Comment: @Tbaki Good for you mate

Answer (score 1):

for better understand you can set label for bucket range.

```
df['AgeBands'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], [0,10,20,30,40,50,max(df['Age'])], labels=range(1,7))
```

output:

```
  Age AgeBands
0   22        3
1   38        4
2   26        3
3   35        4
4   35        4
5   65        6
```

find `df[df['AgeBands'] == 3]`

```
 Age AgeBands
0   22        3
2   26        3
```